# Trying to solve this First Order Differential Equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've made several attempts to this question but they've been unsuccessful. The question is shown below:

$$(1+x^2)\frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}y}+xy=0$$
the answer in the book states when y(0)=2

$$y^2(1+x^2)=4$$ however I gain $c^2=y^2(1+x^2)$ and when the boundary condition is applied this answer is not achieved

Comment: Do you know Laplace transform?

Comment: yes, however, the question requires use of first order differential equation methods

Comment: @JanEerland Wouldn't Laplace method give you a harder equation to work with, due to the $x^2$ term?

Comment: Is your equation correct? Separation gives $\int (x+\frac1x)dx+\int ydy=0$ which integrates to $y^2+x^2+\ln(x^2)=C$, which is quite different from your given solution. While $(1+x^2)y'+xy=0$ will integrate to $y^2(1+x^2)=C$.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're correct - for $x=0$ and $y=2$, we have $c^2 = 2^2 (1 + 0^2)$, so $c^2 = 4$. So, your equation becomes $y^2 (1+x^2) = c^2 = 4$, as required.

Comment: looks like I'm misunderstanding the boundary condition format i assumes that y(0)=2 means when y=0 ,x=2???

Comment: Ah, here's the mistake. $y(0) = 2$ means that when $x=0$, $y=2$. In particular this notation treats $y$ as a function of $x$, as $y(x)$, and says that if you substitute $x=0$ in, we get $y(0) = 2$.